# How would I modify this singly linked list sorting algorithm so that it sorts by ascending order properly?

Tags: c, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a singly linked list in descending order. Realizing there is no straightforward way to do that with only a next pointer, I opted for the approach of sorting the list in ascending order first, then reversing the list, so that the items are sorted in descending order.

**Edit 1:** I'm trying to ensure that the items are stored in descending order based on how frequently they are accessed in the linked list. The printing is just to help me check the order of the linked list.

**Edit 2:** Minimum Working Example as Requested:

main.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    char *name;
    int accessCount;
    struct node_struct *next;
}Knowledge_Node;

int knowledge_put();
int knowledge_get();
void printList();
void sortList();
void reverseList();

Knowledge_Node *head = NULL;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  // Putting James into the linked list
  knowledge_put("James");

  //Get the James node twice
  knowledge_get("James");
  knowledge_get("James");

  //Add Carrie to the linked list
  knowledge_put("Carrie");

  //Get the Carrie node thrice
  knowledge_get("Carrie");
  knowledge_get("Carrie");
  knowledge_get("Carrie");

  // Add adams to linked list
  knowledge_put("Adams");
  knowledge_get("Adams");

  printList();
}
```

Add Node Function

```
int knowledge_put(char * name) {
  Knowledge_Node *node = (Knowledge_Node *)malloc(sizeof(Knowledge_Node));
  if (node == NULL) {
      return -3;
  }
  node->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
  if (node->name == NULL){
      return -3;
  }
  strncpy(node->name, name, strlen(name) + 1);
  node->accessCount = 0;

  node->next = head;
  head = node;

  sortList();
}
```

Retrieve Node Function

```
int knowledge_get(char * name){
    Knowledge_Node *search = head;

    while (search != NULL){
        if (strcmp(search->name, name) == 0){
            search->accessCount = search->accessCount + 1;
            sortList();
            return 0;
        }
        search = search->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Sort List Function:

```
void sortList(){
    Knowledge_Node *temp = head;
    Knowledge_Node *backPtr = head;
    Knowledge_Node *prevNode = NULL;

    while (temp != NULL){
        Knowledge_Node *nextNode = temp->next;
        //currentNode is assigned to temp, which is the pointer used to iterate through the list
        Knowledge_Node *currentNode = temp;
        //Doing a simple check to see if nextNode has something
        if (nextNode != NULL) {

            if(nextNode != NULL){
                if (currentNode->accessCount > nextNode->accessCount) {
                    //If previousNode is NULL it means currentNode is the head of //the linked list
                    //There's different logic to handle each case
                    if (prevNode != NULL){
                        prevNode->next = nextNode;
                        nextNode->next = currentNode;
                        currentNode->next = NULL;
                    } else if (prevNode == NULL){
                        currentNode->next = nextNode->next;
                        nextNode->next = currentNode;
                        head = nextNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Assigning of previousNode. We'll need this for the linking/un-linking //process
        prevNode = currentNode;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    reverseList();
}
```

Reverse List Function:

```
void reverseList(){
    //Initialise three pointers, which we'll use to reverse the links of the 
    //linked list
    Knowledge_Node *prevNode = NULL;
    Knowledge_Node *currentNode = head;
    Knowledge_Node *nextNode = NULL;

    //This is where the linked list reversal is done
    while (currentNode != NULL){
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        currentNode->next = prevNode;
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }

    //Previous Node points to the last node in the original list, so let's 
    //make it the new head
    head = prevNode;
}
```

Print List Function:

```
void printList() {
    Knowledge_Node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%s %d\n", temp->name, temp->accessCount);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Carrie 3
James 2
Adams 1
```

Actual Output:

```
Adams 1
Carrie 3
James 2
```

The ascending sort seems to work fine on its own, without the reverse sort.

Hopefully someone can guide me based on this as to how I can change the sortList algorithm to make it sort in ascending, then descending order properly

**Removed rest of content to keep things brief**

Comment: Can your "reverse print" function be _recursive_? If so, you can sort _ascending_ and merely print the list in reverse order [without _creating_ a reversed list]. Perhaps you _should_ post your reverse/print function. It might help to post your _entire_ code. It should compile _cleanly_ and be downloadable. Also, post your sample data [in a code block]

Comment: @CraigEstey I've added a minimum working example to demonstrate what I want to do, maybe you could help take a look?

Comment: @luckyteos What do you needed to be corrected in your code?

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara Reverse sort is not working appropriately, which is likely caused by the ascending sort not sorting properly. Like for example 3,2,1 should be sorted to 1,2,3, but currently what I get is 2,3,1. Looking for some help to change the behavior of the algorithm so it sorts properly

Comment: @luckyteos the error was in your sorting algorithm not in the reverse  function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is wrong with your sorting algorithm. Since your linked list is a singly linked list you can't use a more efficient sorting algorithm like insert sort. So I used bubble sort in this matter. In your algorithm you have only used a one loop. You must use nested two loops. See details about [bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/).

Also instead of keeping the head pointer for the list as the newly added node, you can define a structure called `List` and have the head pointer in that. It's more clear.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    char *name;
    int accessCount;
    struct node_struct *next;

}Knowledge_Node;


typedef struct list{

    Knowledge_Node* head;
    int count;

}List;

int knowledge_put();
int knowledge_get();
void printList();
void sortList();
void reverseList();

List* list1=NULL;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

   list1= (List*)malloc(sizeof(List)*1);
   list1->head=NULL;
   list1->count=0;
  // Putting James into the linked list
  knowledge_put("James");

  //Get the James node twice
  knowledge_get("James");
  knowledge_get("James");

  //Add Carrie to the linked list
  knowledge_put("Carrie");

  //Get the Carrie node thrice
  knowledge_get("Carrie");
  knowledge_get("Carrie");
  knowledge_get("Carrie");

  // Add adams to linked list
  knowledge_put("Adams");
  knowledge_get("Adams");

  sortList();
  reverseList();
  printList();
}

int knowledge_put(char * name) {
  Knowledge_Node *node = (Knowledge_Node *)malloc(sizeof(Knowledge_Node));
  if (node == NULL) {
      return -3;
  }
  node->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
  if (node->name == NULL){
      return -3;
  }
  strncpy(node->name, name, strlen(name) + 1);
  node->accessCount = 0;


  node->next = list1->head;
  list1->head = node;
  list1->count++;


  return -3;
}

int knowledge_get(char * name){
    Knowledge_Node *search = list1->head;

    while (search != NULL){
        if (strcmp(search->name, name) == 0){
            search->accessCount = search->accessCount + 1;

            return 0;
        }
        search = search->next;
    }
    return -1;
}

void sortList(){

    Knowledge_Node* sort=list1->head;
    Knowledge_Node* nextl=list1->head->next;
    Knowledge_Node* temp=(Knowledge_Node *)malloc(sizeof(Knowledge_Node));
    temp->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    //const Knowledge_Node* c_sort=list1->head;

    for(int i=0;i<list1->count-1;i++){

        while(nextl!=NULL&&sort!=NULL){

            if(sort->accessCount > nextl->accessCount){

                temp->accessCount=sort->accessCount;
                strncpy(temp->name,sort->name,strlen(sort->name)+1);
                sort->accessCount=nextl->accessCount;
                strncpy(sort->name,nextl->name,strlen(nextl->name)+1);
                nextl->accessCount=temp->accessCount;
                strncpy(nextl->name,temp->name,strlen(temp->name)+1);

            }
            sort=sort->next;
            nextl=nextl->next;

        }
        sort=list1->head;
        nextl=list1->head->next;

    }


}

void reverseList(){
    //Initialise three pointers, which we'll use to reverse the links of the
    //linked list
    Knowledge_Node *prevNode = NULL;
    Knowledge_Node *currentNode = list1->head;
    Knowledge_Node *nextNode = NULL;

    //This is where the linked list reversal is done
    while (currentNode != NULL){
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        currentNode->next = prevNode;
        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }

    //Previous Node points to the last node in the original list, so let's
    //make it the new head
    list1->head = prevNode;
}

void printList() {
    Knowledge_Node *temp = list1->head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%s %d\n", temp->name, temp->accessCount);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I've been spending quite some time trying to wrap my mind over this, especially when there are so many pointers involved. Though, what I was trying to do initially was do what you did above, but by re-linking the nodes instead, but always ran into a issue of what is the previous node and how should I compare it with all the other nodes to check its in the correct place. Thanks for telling me that's not possible with a singly linked list.

Comment: @luckyteos Yes if you want to check with previous nodes you must have a doubly linked list.